# How can we make interfaces from multiple .ts files accessible from one file?

Tags: typescript

I'm building an Angular app that will have a lot of interfaces. From my previous experience putting all my interfaces into one file I decided it might be better this time to make multiple files and import them all into one file which I add to the `paths` object in my `config.ts` file to make it accessible from one name rather than a long relative path.  I'm thinking I would have to do something like this

```
import { * as SomeAlias01 } from './my-interfacesA.ts';
import { * as SomeAlias02 } from './my-interfacesB.ts';

export SomeAlias01;
export SomeAlias02;
```

But doing it this way I'm guessing I would have to use them in my app like this

```
SomeVar : SomeAlias01.SomeInterface = 'some value';
```

If that's the case, it would become pretty cumbersome after a while as it will become

```
SomeVar : SomeAlias01.AnotherAlias.MoreAliases.SomeInterface = 'some value';
```

How can this be done to expose each interface in a way that allows me to just import them without the chain of aliases?

Comment: Why not import from the place where the interface is defined (`export interface SomeInterface {}`)? Code Completion & Auto Imports can usually figure out what to import from where. And maybe you can also reduce the amount of interfaces, the goal should be to have as few as possible. Inheritance, generics, etc exist for that purpose